# adding datarow to datagridview only adding to first column

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to pull a set of data from a database and shove it in to a datagridview. Problem is, when I do this, I get "system.data.datarow", and it only adds it to the first column (I've got 5). Here's my code.

```
SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("some SQL query string", "SQL database connection info");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
DataTable table = new Datatable();

if (methodType = "SELECT")
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    adapter.fill(table);
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        dgvCrsLookupResults.Rows.Add(row[0]);
        dgvCrsLookupResults.Rows.Add(row[1]);
        dgvCrsLookupResults.Rows.Add(row[2]);
        dgvCrsLookupResults.Rows.Add(row[3]);
        dgvCrsLookupResults.Rows.Add(row[4]);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this only fills in the first column, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to add it to each column instead. When I use

```
dgvCrsLookupResults.Columns.Add(row[0]);
```

It just says that it has invalid arguments. I know I'm damn close, but I'm new to all of this, so I'm completely lost as to how to make that last jump. Thoughts?

Comment: what is the data type of the rows that you are trying to add.. do you need to perhaps do some casting..? it's hard to tell what your structure is based on that little bit of code..

Comment: I've updated the code to show everything relevant. Does this help?

Comment: instead of trying to do the row based on the Index try something like this 
`dgvCrsLookupResults.Rows.Add(row["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());` `Replace COLUMN_NAME` with the actual Column Name.. never rely on Indexes uses the actual Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping `foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)` use:

```
dgvCrsLookupResults.DataSource = table;
```

Remember set:

```
dgvCrsLookupResults.AutoGenerateColumns = True;
```

Or in designer create a columns for your DataGridView.

In column set `DataPropertyName` = ColumnName in `DataTable`

In this case -> `dgvCrsLookupResults.AutoGenerateColumns = False;`